# Can't start NavigationDrawerActivity ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-imageview

I am exhausted with ImageView, the application works correctly, the problem is when I add new ImageViews:

When I add an ImageView to a CardView to use it in a RecyclerView inside of a fragment_home the NavigationDrawerActivity returns the next **error**:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.twittor, PID: 11720
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twittor/com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3375)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**More info:**

- The PrincipalActivity is the NavigationDrawerActivity that Android Studio create automatically
- If I delete the id of the ImageViewer the app stops crashing

Comment: Check line number 54 of your PrincipalActivity.java class

Comment: `NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);`

Comment: I've seen that if I delete the id of the ImageViewer the app stop crashing. Now the problem is that I can't use it with onClick or other stuff

Answer (score 1):

try accessing the NavController in the onPostCreate method. The issue probably is the view not being initiated when you try to access it.
I had a similar issue and resolved it by

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

    val navController=findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)

}
```